# Concept of independence in card matching problem

Tags: probability, independence

I am doing an introduction to probability book and the following problem was presented.

> Consider a well-shuffled deck
> of n cards, labeled 1 through n. You flip over the cards one by one, saying the
> numbers 1 through n as you do so. You win the game if, at some point, the number
> you say aloud is the same as the number on the card being flipped over (for example,
> if the 7th card in the deck has the label 7).

Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ card in the deck has the number $i$ written on it.The solution starts off by saying that $P(A_i)=\frac{1}{n}$. While I can understand the reasoning that since only 1 card will match the position, the probability is therefore $\frac{1}{n}$, is it not also true that the probability distribution of $A_i$ is conditioned on $A_i$? So how can we say that $P(A_i)$ is simply $\frac{1}{n}$?

For example, we cannot use binomial distribution to solve this problem because $P(No\ match)\neq(1−\frac{1}{n})^n$. Does this not show that $P(A_i)\neq\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: The probability that none of the cards match is the probability of a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).